# How to render an Angular variable containing HTML in view?

Tags: html, angularjs

I have a data that contains HTML (for exemple I have `<b>XXXX</b>`) and I would like to display it as:

**XXXX**

I want this to be rendered as bold when it gets displayed on view.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `AngularJS` you can use `ng-bind-html` to render the html on view.

it will make your content **XXXX** bold.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`ng-bind-html`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml) that exaclty do what you are looking for.

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngSanitize']);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.text = "<b>XXXX</b>";
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.1/angular-sanitize.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <div ng-bind-html="text"></div>
</div>
```

---

*Note that you will have to include [`ngSanitize`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngSanitize/service/$sanitize) in your dependencies to be able to use it.*

## Test it on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Mistalis/pmy9n2aq/)!